# How to insert a random string into the sed 's//' replace string for each line actioned?

Tags: bash, shell, random, sed

This:

`echo "    " | tr ' ' '\n' | sed "s|.*|$RANDOM|"`

Or this:

`echo "    " | tr ' ' '\n' | sed "s|.*|$(echo $RANDOM)|"`

Will print a list of 5 numbers (space is replaced by newline, sed replaces each line with $RANDOM), and those 5 numbers **will all be the same**:

```
$ echo "    " | tr ' ' '\n' | sed "s|.*|$(echo $RANDOM)|"
21590
21590
21590
21590
21590
```

This is because the replace of $RANDOM to a random value happens only once.

What is the easiest and shortest way, preferably by only using sed, to actually print a **different** random number for each line. i.e. to provide some "secondary input stream" which differs for each line that sed handles?

I could do it with xargs, but I wonder if there is a way to do it with sed only.

Comment: Why do you need to use `sed`? All you need is a random line on each line?

Comment: No, it this is just a simplified example. There are other ways to do it, but the question is if it is possible in sed.

Comment: Don't think `sed` has an internal construct to generate random numbers. `awk` has

Comment: It seems your question has gotten some attention and several answers. Could you please provide a follow-up sharing how you eventually solved your problem, which of the answers you found most useful, and possibly adding some details about the context where this snippet is being used?

Comment: @simlev, thank you for reminding me. I've given feedback on each of the answers. Paul Hodges comes closest to the "all-in-sed" (with sed's eval/execute option used to create a subshell) solution, and he adds a nice "custom length" printf at the same time. potong has a worthy second place which uses a similar approach.

Comment: @Roel Yes, that's the answer I upvoted as well. I mostly use Perl instead of `sed`, so I was curious to understand the reasons for this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the following:

```
$ seq 5 | sed "s/.*/date +%N | grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'/e"
16794
76358
17143
60690
70506
```

It uses the last 5 numbers of the nanosecond timer to generate a reasonably random entropy quality random number.

Comment: Spawning a subshell to call `date` once per input line would be immensely slow. Literally thousands of times slower than calling `rand()` from awk as in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56404749/1745001)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your version of `sed`, but -

```
$: cat x
a
b
c
d
e

$: sed 's/.*/printf "%05d\n" $RANDOM/e' x
30181
30514
24742
28555
26267
```

The `e` means `e`*xecute*, and spawns a subshell, so be wary of the cost.

## addendum

You can format output. `printf "%07.7s\n" $(($RANDOM%10000))$(($RANDOM%10000))` will always print 7 digits with leading zero pad, and ameliorate the constraints from the default range, which makes 10000 numbers that starts with 1, 10000 numbers that start with 2, and 2,767 that start with 3 out of a total of 32,767 *aside* from those in the normal 0-9999 range - not an ideal distribution. You might also just use `awk` for better random numbers.

Comment: Very cool answer, love it. Nice job Paul. I was not aware of the `e` execute/eval option in sed. Subshells are quite acceptable.

Comment: Or, with only minimal changes to what the OP had tried: `echo "    " | tr ' ' '\n' | sed 's|.*|echo $RANDOM|e'`.

Comment: @simlev nice! Thank you for all your input on the question too

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this does not seem to work anymore. `sed 4.7` in `Bash 5.0.17(1)`

Answer (score 2):

No, it is impossible to do this with sed only as sed has no capability to generate random numbers. It's not even sed that's doing it in your posted example, it's the shell generating a random number before sed is called. All sed sees is `"s|.*|21590|"`.

If you want to do this using standard tools in any shell on any UNIX box then you can do this with any awk:

```
$ echo "    " | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '{sub(/.*/,rand())}1'
0.924046
0.593909
0.306394
0.578941
0.740133
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Numeric-Functions for more info on `rand()` and I can provide C&V if you're interested in pursuing an awk solution.

---

One way to address your comment below:

```
$ seq 5 | awk -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} {print rand()}'
0.0873814
0.536876
0.535788
0.881146
0.354652
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it is the shell in my example, hence the question. Thanks for the awk alternative, great idea.

Comment: This is regrettably not really usable. The numbers generated are the same each time (even between your output and mine it's the same!), and trying to preset entropy leads to all numbers being the same when a pipe is used, see: `seq 5 | awk '{srand();print rand()}'`

Comment: That is not how you would solve that problem as srand() seeds based on the current time by default and rand() uses the previous value as a seed so you're forcing it to always output the same number for every line. I've added one approach to this but it's been 2 years since you asked this question - ask a new followup question if you'd like help.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**

What is the easiest and shortest way, *preferably* by only using sed, to actually print a different random number for each line?

**Answer:**

```
echo "    " | tr ' ' '\n' | perl -pe 's|.*|int(rand(89999))+10000|e'
```

or simply:

```
perl -e 'printf "%05s\n",int(rand(100000)) for (1..5)'
```

**Explanation:**

I don't see why one shoudn't use Perl, or any tool that's possibly more suitable for the job. In the OP there's no hint of a reason to stick to `sed`, which is on the contrary only denoted as a preference.

I wonder why one would go through a substitution in order to print five random numbers. No details are given about the bigger picture, but it certainly makes me curious.

Comment: Thank you for the Perl alternative, great idea!

Comment: Great answer really. Works always `seq 5 | perl -pe 's|.*|int(rand(89999))+10000|e'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and Bash):

```
seq 5 | sed 's/.*/echo $RANDOM/e'
```

This replaces the numbers 1 to 5 by `echo $RANDOM` and evaluates each line.

N.B. GNU sed uses `/bin/sh` which may be directed via a symbolic link to `/bin/dash` in which case the environmental variable `$RANDOM` will not be found. There are various solutions to get around this but probably the easiest (though possibly dangerous) is:

```
sudo ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
# run sed
sudo ln -sf /bin/dash /bin/sh
```

Another alternaive:

```
shuf -i 1-100000 -n 5
```

Comment: Very similar to Paul's answer. I did not know about the in-sed eval option. Great.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this does not seem to work anymore. `sed 4.7` in `Bash 5.0.17(1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same random number

```
random=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd '0-9' | head -c 5)
echo -e "$random\n$random\n$random\n$random\n$random"
```

If you want a different number each time. The problem here is its harder to set how many characters you get

```
echo -e "$RANDOM\n$RANDOM\n$RANDOM\n$RANDOM\n$RANDOM"
```

Or more logically for the same number

```
random=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd '0-5' | head -c 8)
x=0
while (($x < 5)); do echo "$random";((x++));done
```

or more logically for a different number

```
x=0
while (($x < 5)); do random=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd '0-5' | head -c 8); echo "$random";((x++));done
```

Comment: Thank you Goose. I already these type of approaches, I was looking for a sed solution, as per the original question. Normally I would down vote this, but you have done good effort and you're quite new on the platform, so I won't. Please keep in mind to answer the original question whenever answering questions. Surrounding info is acceptable imho too, but then it should be clearly indicated that you were aware that it differs from the original question imho. Thank you & God bless.